# float:left percentage div

Tags: html, grid, css-float, responsive-design

I have a few percentage-sized divs and at screen `max-width:1030px` the divs are at 50%. But the fifth div leaves a blank space before continuing.

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stevenspiel/nYabE/)

[image]

I have no idea why. [Check out the demo here](http://new.stevenspiel.com/compositions) (screen size must be smaller than 1030px to see it)

HTML

```
<div class="video-grid">
    <div class="vimeo">
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/991/435991395_640.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo">
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/436/269/436269192_640.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo"> 
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/436/115/436115827_640.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo"> 
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/991/435991608_640.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo"> 
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/991/435991608_640.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo"> 
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://new.stevenspiel.com/wp-content/themes/Photum/images/kiss.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo"> 
        <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65191942?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=dd4c23">
            <img alt="" src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/435/991/435991206_640.jpg" />
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video-grid {
    width:100%;
}

.vimeo {
    max-width:400px;
    min-width:250px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}

.vimeo img {
    width:90%;
    padding:5%;
}


@media screen and (max-width:1030px) {
    .vimeo {
        width:50%;
        min-width: 170px;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1st column, 3rd row down. I'll post a picture

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to shrink my browser width. I deleted the image above the blank space, and all the images spaced as intended. The picture above the white space is slightly too tall; it's blocking the picture to the right of the white space from floating properly to the left. You can fix this by adding a height attribute to all of the pictures (make sure they're all the same), or simply shrinking that one photo

Comment: your third image is 1 pixel higher then the others, which causes the fifth image's to float to 'hook' behind it. Fix the height issue, or add some sort of `clear` on every second element inside your media query

Comment: @PeterVR would a `clear` on every second element effect the layout when there are three per row?

Comment: Yes, that's why you should put it inside your media query. And you should google the :nth-child pseudo class, cause it will come in handy here...

Comment: if you want to put it in the form of an answer, I'll accept it (if you're a points person). --again, I appreciate it.

Comment: This is what did it `.vimeo:nth-child(odd) {clear:both;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your media query:

```
.vimeo:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
   clear:both;
}
```

Basically, it just adds a clear class to every second image, i.e. 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 etc.

Just keep in mind that the browser support (IE) can be problematic – see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), but if you aren't bothered about those still using IE8 and below then this will work perfectly!

Good luck.

**EDIT** It might also be wise to add in a clear class for the full size as well not just the media query.

Here is the full CSS. Note that the media query now removes the clear class from the (3n-2) selector as well before reapplying it so as to avoid clearing extra divs that you wouldn't want.

Hope that helps!

```
.video-grid {
    width:100%;
}
.vimeo {
    max-width:400px;
    min-width:250px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.vimeo:nth-of-type(3n-2) {
    clear:both;
}
.vimeo img {
    width:90%;
    padding:5%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1030px) {
    .vimeo {
        width:50%;
        min-width: 170px;
    }
    .vimeo:nth-of-type(3n-2) {
        clear:none;
    }
    .vimeo:nth-of-type(2n-1) {
       clear:both;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add either `height="216px"` or `max-height` to the `.vimeo` element

```
    .vimeo {
        max-width:400px;
        max-height:216px;;
        width:33%;
        float:left; 

}
```

The element before has a slightly taller height and is pushing/creating that extra space

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/ubH5h/

Comment: Because of the reponsive layout, I'm still getting issues (even in the jsfiddle) as I resize the screen. Also, for larger screens, I still would like the image to be taller.